# How to check the source of memory leakage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application which is made in angularjs. It's kind of monitoring application that using lots of charts. The application runs continuously and the problem is on IE, after 1.5 to 2 days, application crashes. I think there is a problem of memory leakage. I checked it on chrome and on IE as well using developer tools heap snapshot. Size and number of objects increase very slowly. Also sometimes it decreases. Is there any tool through which i can see the source of memory leakage? because we are using third libraries for charts as well.

Comment: are you using any iframe in your application.

Comment: You can use the *Memory Tab* in Chrome dev tools to isolate memory leaks, more specifically the *Record allocation timeline* feature

Comment: yes we are using iframe on 2 to 3 place @ManojPilania

Comment: update your jquery ui to latest version it will resolve, after updating jquery ui problem still persist then generate custom jquery ui without datetime picker control. in jquery ui datetime picker control has memory leakage.